# Media-assisted Greek learning

Tags: learning-methods, greek

As described in an excellent post, watching a movie multiple times with and without subtitles greatly improves comprehension. 
I did a similar thing with books once: I knew the L1 version and read the L2 with the L1 as support.

Learning Greek, this has not helped yet due to the lack of seeing what is what. I have no idea about all pronouns yet, and weak vocabulary: not the best requirements for media-assisted learning.

Now I'd like to watch or read a simple movie / book with common, simple phrases in some kind of story, like a children's book. Not too much past tense or complex sentences, everything easy.

I've been thinking about *The Lion King* and similar. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning.SE! This site is a Question&Answer site, not a chat board. Your question, however, looks like it invites for an open-ended discussion, which is not appreciated. Can you please re-phrase your question so it were more specific and could be objectively answered? I think it is easy to salvage if you specify what exactly you need. Resources/libraries/websites? Having some difficulty using this learning technique? Teaching adults vs. teaching children?

Comment: I think there are two questions here: 1. Good sources for simple Greek, as outlined in the question. 2. Is this a good way of learning? I think question number 2 has been answered somewhere on the site already, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @TommiBrander I have rephrased the question a bit so it only asks about resources.